# Query including subquery and group by slower than expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, subquery

The whole query below runs incredibly slowly.

The subquery query [alias Stage_1] takes only 1.37 minutes returning 9514 records, however the whole query takes over 20 minutes, returning 2606 records.

I could use a #temp table to hold the subquery to improve the performance however I would prefer not to.

An overview of the query is that table WeeklySpace inner joins to Spaceblock_Name_to_PG table on SpaceblockName_SID, this cuts down the results in WeeklySpace and includes PG_Code with the results in WeeklySpace. WeeklySpace is then Full Outer Joined to Sales_PG_Wk across 3 fields. The where clause focuses the results, and may be changed. The results from the subquery are then sum'd. You cannot do the final sum'ing in the subquery due to the group by and sum over used.

I believe the issue is due to the subquery re calculation repeatedly during the group by in the final sum'ing. The field SpaceblockName_SID also appears to be involved in causing the issue as without it the run time with a group by in the subquery isn't affected.

I have read though loads of suggestion, trying them all to resolve the issue.

These include;

- Adding TOP 2147483647 with Order by to force intermediate
  materialization, both in the subquery and using a CTE.
- Adding a join after stage_1.
- Cast'ing SpaceblockName_SID from an int to a varchar and back again

The execution plan (cut in two parts, shown below the code) for both the subquery and the whole query appear similar. The cost is around the Full Outer Join (Hash Match), which I expected.

The query is running on T-SQL 2005.

Any help greatly appreciated!

```
select 
    Cost_centre
    , Fin_week
    , SpaceblockName_SID
    , sum(Propor_rep_SRV) as Total_SpaceblockName_SID_SRV
from
(
        select  
            coalesce(space_side.fin_week , sales_side.fin_week) as Fin_week 
           ,coalesce(space_side.cost_centre , sales_side.cost_Centre) as Cost_centre 
           ,space_side.SpaceblockName_SID
           ,case
                when  space_side.SpaceblockName_SID is null
                    then sales_side.SalesExVAT
                else  sum(space_side.TLM)
                                /nullif(sum (sum(space_side.TLM) ) over (partition by coalesce(space_side.fin_week , sales_side.fin_week)
                                                                                            , coalesce(space_side.cost_centre , sales_side.cost_Centre)  
                                                                                            , coalesce( Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.PG_Code, sales_side.PG_Code)) ,0)*sales_side.SalesExVAT 
            end as Propor_rep_SRV
        from
            WeeklySpace as space_side
        INNER JOIN
            Spaceblock_Name_to_PG 
                ON space_side.SpaceblockName_SID = Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.SpaceblockName_SID 
                    and Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.PG_Code < 10000
        full outer join
            sales_pg_wk as sales_side
                on  space_side.fin_week = sales_side.fin_week 
                    and space_side.Cost_Centre = sales_side.Cost_Centre 
                    and Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.PG_code = sales_side.pg_code
        where 
            coalesce(space_side.fin_week, sales_side.fin_week) between 201538 and 201550
                and
            coalesce(space_side.cost_centre, sales_side.cost_Centre) in (3, 2800)
        group by  
            coalesce(space_side.fin_week, sales_side.fin_week)  
           ,coalesce(space_side.cost_centre, sales_side.cost_Centre)  
           ,coalesce( Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.PG_Code, sales_side.PG_Code)  
           ,sales_side.SalesExVAT
           ,space_side.SpaceblockName_SID
) as stage_1
group by 
    Cost_centre
    , Fin_week
    , SpaceblockName_SID
```

---

Execution plan left hand side
[image: Execution plan left hand side]

---

Execution plan right hand side
[image: Execution plan left hand side]

Comment: You say you can solve the problem but using a temp table, but don't want to do this. Can I ask why? Unless you need to make the query a view this seems like a viable option. I have spent longer than I would care to admit trying to sort out issues where I needed forced materialisation and have admitted defeat in almost all instances, either deciding that I will use a multi-step table valued function and use a table variable to force materialisation or that I will use a stored procedure and a temp table.

Comment: @GarethD . Thanks for taking the time to look at it. Originally the reason for not using a temp table was exactly as you said, so I could have a view.  The second, and main, reason is that the code is used with a reporting system used be a number of different individuals. Having a temp table creates its own problems with the reporting system.

Comment: 'Having a temp table creates its own problems with the reporting system.' - How?

Comment: I think the long and the short of it is that unless anything ever comes of [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/provide-a-hint-to-force-intermediate-materialization-of-ctes-or-derived-tables), there is not going to be one guaranteed way of achieving this. There are various workarounds like you have mentioned, and you can try various hints to try to force the eager spool over the lazy spool, but these are going to vary based on your table structure and statistics.

Comment: @Mark Sinkinson. Thanks for looking at it. The reporting is run through Excel using an ADODB.Connection. Due to the way the connection works, temp tables have to be ## not #. For that reason you have to have different names for each table for different users. We have done this with other reports, but we use injection code, which isn't ideal.

Comment: To get around the ADODB issue could you not use a stored procedure, then just call the procedure from excel?

Comment: @GarethD. Thanks again. Yes, I tried the suggestion on your link. To be honest I only posted the question as I had run out of ideas and suggestions already posted. Looks like crunching down the data into its own table is the best option. At least I can then index it efficiently.

Comment: @GarethD. On the ADODB. You can, and thats how I sorted it with something else. But it makes the code overly complex. You also have to pass specific variables, you can't just 'where' the thing. The other, and main, reason is that the results are going to be joined to something else and used in further calculations. Good suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mentioned about indices are created or not on those columns those you used in your query. If not then create and check performance of the query

Comment: Thanks for looking. The tables are indexed, you can see this in the execution plan. The indexing being used is unique noncluster. As the subquery runs ok I don't think its a indexing issue.

Answer (score 0):

In looking at you logic I think you split this in two with a UNION
One with Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.PG_Code < 10000 and the other with Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.PG_Code >= 10000

And consider this change
If may be doing a bunch of join that you are going to throw out anyway

```
full outer join sales_pg_wk as sales_side
  on  space_side.fin_week = sales_side.fin_week 
      and space_side.Cost_Centre = sales_side.Cost_Centre 
      and Spaceblock_Name_to_PG.PG_code = sales_side.pg_code
      and space_side.fin_week between 201538 and 201550 
      and sales_side.fin_week between 201538 and 201550
      and space_side.cost_centre in (3, 2800)
      and sales_side.cost_Centre in (3, 2800)
```

Comment: @ Blam . Could you explain the 'union' piece a bit more? Sorry I don't get how it would help as the records for PG_Code >= 10000 aren't required, hence the removal though the join (in case it helps, PG_code >= 10000 don't exist in the Sales_side.) On the adding join conditions to the full outer. It slows the thing right down. As I mentioned, the subquery runs fine, its adding the final aggregation with the group by that not working. Thanks for looking.

Comment: Then I don't follow this "when  space_side.SpaceblockName_SID is null".  So that subquery runs fine alone.  Most likely you have a case of it runs many times.  What is the big deal with materializing the subquery in a #temp?  The would be all of 4 lines of code on a query that is already 40 lines long.

Comment: @ Blam . Thanks for coming back to me.  The  "when space_side.SpaceblockName_SID is null" covers when there is no TLM, the sales still exist so are attributed to null space otherwise its lost by multiplying it by null. The issue with using a temp table is described ion the comments to GarethD under the question, however looking at the feedback im starting to think its the only and best option.

Comment: And again when space_side.SpaceblockName_SID is null could be covered by a union.  One select deals the null and the other not null.

Comment: @ Blam . I've tried breaking it down into two parts with union. Its run slower than before, but maybe I have misunderstood your answer. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @MKC Ouch     I think there is a way to slice and dice it to make it work but it is just too complex.  If you could break it down to a more simple query that goes bad I will take a look at it.